# Scaling PDF up from A4 to A3 for printing?

Tags: pdf, printer

I have a PDF document that is formatted in A4. It consists of dozens of pages of diagrams and is far to small to read comfortably when printed. Is there anyway to scale the document up to A3 for printing?

I would have assumed this could be done from the printer preferences or page setup preferences in acrobat but I can't see anything!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I gather Print dialog/Page Handling/Page scaling/Fit to printable area ... should do it, as long as you have A3 setted up on your printer.

Comment: Hmm, I don't seem to have that option. Perhaps a driver issue.

Comment: @Steve Homer - Uhmm, I don't think so. Are you using Acrobat Reader ?

Comment: @Idigas, yes latest version of Reader.

Comment: Okay - taken another look following the answer below. You're quite right and I've no idea how I missed it.

Answer (score 11):

Using [Ghostscript](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/):

```
gswin32c.exe -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sPAPERSIZE=a3 -dFIXEDMEDIA -dPDFFitPage -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf
```

Comment: Thank you!  It's /usr/bin/gs and A0/A1 here on ALT though :)

Answer (score 2):

No need to scale the PDF ***file*** if you only need the ***paper printout*** scaled up to A3. Acrobat reader (latest version is 9.3.1) most definitely has an option to do that. It can scale any PDF page up or down to any available media size of your printer.

The setting can be found in the lower left quarter of the front page on the printing dialog of the Acrobat/AcroReader. You should find the area 'page settings' with the drop-down list 'adapt page size' with some additional checkmarks to enable/disable (quoted strings translated from German back to English). This can even be used to create n-up printouts or pamphlet imposition from plain A4, letter or other PDF pagesizes.